# Was bad grub on dual boot (Ubuntu 17.10 & W10) cured by moving partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, boot-repair

Summary: Did moving my ubuntu partitions solve a common grub problem?

A common issue seems to be getting grub to work on a dual boot computer; e.g., ubuntu and w10.

Bad grub gave me indigestion after I resized/moved the U17.10 boot partition. Yes - gparted warned me of potential issues, but I didn't realize it would take a day out of my life . . .

After many attempts using a live usb (the "usb I installed from"), and many suggested solutions, I could not get past a grub screen with options for (approximately):

1. ubuntu - which worked fine
2. advanced options for ubuntu - which worked as far as tested
   3-5. 3 references to windows - with various names - none of which worked
   6-7. 2 additional references to ubuntu - neither of which worked
3. go to setup - which worked

One approach I used was Boot-Repair: I noticed that it mentioned that my boot partition was far away from the start of the disk it was on, and might not be found. Indeed, for some reason, I decided during installation to put U17.10 in the 150 Gb at the tail end of a 2 Tb disk. the rest of the disk was not used.

So, after backing up my data, I moved U17.10 to the front of the 2 Tb drive. After running Boot-Repair once again, I can now get to both W10 and U17.10 from the grub menu.

BTW: I have seen a post that basically reports the same result.

Does this make sense?

Tim

Comment: If an old system using IDE, the far from start may apply. There was a BIOS limit of 137GB where all boot files had to be inside that. But that was IDE, not seen with AHCI, nor any newer UEFI systems. Have seen similar issue on USB drives as they are not AHCI. Is system UEFI or BIOS. Most often Windows 10 is UEFI as all pre-installed Windows must be UEFI. If upgrade from Windows 7 probably BIOS, as only a few Windows 7 systems were pre-installed in UEFI mode. So is system UEFI or BIOS? Post details from Boot-Repair summary report, altough would have been better before.

Comment: Oldfred: Thanks for the feedback. The system is UEFI. Pre-installed W10. I added U17.10 upon receipt, with some help (from you and others). Dual boot worked fine until I tweaked the root partition created at install. Perhaps it is just happenstance that moving the (3) Ubuntu related partitions (root, home, swap) seemed to solve the problem. Hmmm. I did also create a swap partition "in front of" (relative to the disk's start) when I tweaked the root's size.